# Return null values as undefined in pg-promise queries

Tags: pg-promise

Just a simple question. Is there any way to tweak pg-promise return datasets (those from calling `db.one('select user_id, location, created_by from svc.users')` etc.) such that `null` values are always returned as `undefined` instead, under all circumstances?

So instead of returning: `{ user_id: "andrew", location: null, created_by: "alex" }`,

it will return `{ user_id: "andrew", location: undefined, created_by: "alex" }`.

Comment: This is async JavaScript, you are free to twist returned values as you like. Why do want to bind it to a library, when you can just transform it on your end?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I can, just wondering if there is a way to do this from this library without additional code ( since this excellent library got so many features that can achieve so many things already :D )

Comment: You can use event [receive](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:receive) to do any extra transformation on the query result.